# How to get date time format from javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to display date of today according the current datetime format without displaying the seconds

Thanks for help

Comment: What's the "current datetime format" you're looking for?

Answer (score 2):

You have to write some code yourself to do it, or you could use a library like [Date.js](http://datejs.com).

JavaScript "Date" object instances have methods like `.getFullYear()`, `.getMonth()`, `.getDate()`, and so on. (Be aware that `.getMonth()` returns numbers from 0 through 11, not 1 through 12.)

Comment: Actually this will help to write the date but will not keep the format as it is in Datetime settings

Comment: What do you mean, "Datetime settings"?

Comment: Datetime settings in control panel for example English(United States)

Comment: You can't access those settings from Javascript.  Thus, you can either use whatever default the Javascript runtime wants to give you, or you can control the formatting yourself.